# Get unread conversations gmail

Tags: android, api, count, gmail

I want to get an int with the number of unread emails in the accounts of the device.
I have seen that there is a new way to do this using the "Gmail Labels Public API"

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html

I have read the documentation and downloaded the sample application and it really works.
But I have two problems: (

My intention is to get an int with the number of unread conversations, i try this:

```
String unread = GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS.toString();
```

but not works, always returns `"numUnreadConversations"`

How I can get an int to this value?

My second problem is this: The code works correctly with the default count of my device, but I want to get the value with all unread conversations of all device gmail accounts

eally appreciate any help

thanks and regards

Comment: If you are trying to get a int why are you creating a string variable and passing the number tostring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS.toString();` you're just converting the enum to string.

You need a Cursor object to iterate through labels and then acquire the number with `cursor.getInt(GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS)`

Check this [code](https://code.google.com/p/dashclock/source/browse/main/src/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/gmail/GmailExtension.java?r=cfe9dea416128620d7893a064040b541cbb816ca) for iterating through accounts and labels.

Comment: I'm using this code as a reference, I am also using cursor.getInt (GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS) but without success, always indicates 0. The permissions are correct. This is a link to my code. I do not know I'm doing wrong http://ul.to/u5gplc7n

Comment: Nice, I got it working, the only problem was that there's no unread mail in `CANONICAL_NAME_INBOX` for me. If you set `labelCanonical = GmailContract.Labels.LabelCanonicalNames.CANONICAL_NAME_ALL_MAIL;` you'll get all unread mails. Use logcat to see what labels you have, print something like `Log.d("GMAIL", cursor.getString(LabelsQuery.CANONICAL_NAME) + " unread:" + cursor.getInt(LabelsQuery.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS));` in `while (cursor.moveToNext())` loop.